# filling list with the same integer in prolog

Tags: list, prolog, logic

I want to write a function that fill in the list with the same number on prolog. For example, I want the list `[_,_,1,_]` to be `[1,1,1,1]` or if the list is all empty `[_,_,_,_]` it will result in a number of my choice, 5 for example. Can anyone help me with that?

Comment: Prolog doesn't have functions. Do you mean a predicate?

Answer (score 3):

Simplest:

```
?- L = [_,_,1,_], maplist(=(_), L).
L = [1,1,1,1].
```

Answer (score 2):

Simple:

```
all(_,[],[]).
all(H,[H|T],[H|T]) :- all(H,T,T).
```

That gives me:

```
?- all(_,[_,_,1,_],Xs).
Xs = [1, 1, 1, 1].

?- all(5,[_,_,_,_],Xs).
Xs = [5, 5, 5, 5].

?- all(5,[_,_,1,_],Xs).
false.

?- all(_,[3,_,1,_],Xs).
false.
```

Comment: Isn't your `R` just a pointless duplicate of `T`?

Comment: @brebs - Yes, good spotting. You're 100% right.

Comment: It's still a duplicate. No need for that third argument. Should be `all/2`

Answer (score -1):

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

fill(Ls, Value) :-
    chain(Ls, #=),
    Ls = [Value|_].
```

e.g.

```
?- Ls = [_,_,1,_], fill(Ls, V).
Ls = [1, 1, 1, 1],
V = 1

?- Ls = [_,_,_,_], fill(Ls, 5).
Ls = [5, 5, 5, 5]

?- Ls = [_,_,1,_], fill(Ls, 7).
false
```